# HP EliteBook 8540p fingerprint not found (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu-drivers, fingerprint-reader

I can't get fingerprint reader to work on Ubuntu 16.04
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your fingerprint reader is **138a:0007 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS451**

It's not in the supported model of [fingerprint-gui project](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui), therefore it's not working for sure.

You can found a bug report for this device [here on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/fingerprint-gui/+bug/745505).

Comment: It's working on windows. It's not supported thanks.